# How to test statistical improvement under model prediction uncertainty?

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models, validation, uncertainty

I have a regression model, predicting a popularity of a text. I have its performance metrics on test set, e.g. RMSE and MAE. This gives me an uncertainty estimate about its predictions.

Now I want to transform the text in some way, e.g. give it to human experts or another model to "upgrade" (in terms of getting better popularity). So I have the original and transformed text.

Now I have 3 popularity scores:

- true popularity for original text
- predicted popularity for original text
- predicted popularity for transformed text

Obviously, if model MAE is for example around 5, and predicted popularity for transformed text is higher than for the original by 1.5, this can be totally random, due to errors in the model prediction.

How can I measure if text transformation is beneficial, i.e. statistically significantly better than the original text, incorporating information about model quality? Requiring that the improvement has to be higher than model error would be incredibly strict.

Comment: I guess you are using this approach since you have no true popularity for any transformed texts, right?

Comment: @picky_porpoise exactly. If I did, it would be easy. But I could only do this for new texts with A/B tests, which is costly and comes with its own problems. So I want to use historical data, which I have quite a lot of.